# Exposed SQLite connection fails with SQLITE_BUSY

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I'm trying to build an application using Ktor and Exposed with SQLite. Unfortunately my application keeps crashing.

This is my database connection:

```kotlin
class DatabaseFactory(connection: DatabaseConnection) {
    init {
        connect()
        createSchema()
    }

    private fun connect() {
        Database.connect("jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/file", "org.sqlite.JDBC")
        TransactionManager.manager.defaultIsolationLevel = Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE
    }

    private fun createSchema() {
        transaction {
            SchemaUtils.create(Images)
            SchemaUtils.create(KeyValues)

            Images.deleteAll()
        }
    }

    suspend fun <T> dbQuery(block: () -> T): T =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            transaction { block() }
        }
}

// access db with
DatabaseFactory.dbQuery {
    // do stuff
}
```

While running my application I get the following error:

```
org.jetbrains.exposed.exceptions.ExposedSQLException: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use coroutines and run your code in `Dispatchers.IO` your queries could be executed in separate threads what treated as `multiple processes` which only could read from SQLite instance.

[More on SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)

Comment: How do I make sure that there is a single connection only?